# How to fix badly virused android device - Your device has been modified, software updates are not available

Tags: samsung, samsung-galaxy-note-10.1, rom-update

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10.1 that has been infected with some viruses really badly.

After factory defaults, as soon as it connects to the internet it starts downloading some apps and advertisement windows pop up like every 10 seconds.

Things I tried:

- Installed AVG AntiVirus, CM serurity, Clear master

  - It helped me delete some files of the virus but did not solve the problem
- Booted into recovery mode:

  - Wiped cache partition
  - wiped data/factory reset
- Booted into Odin mode:

  - Product Name: GT-N8010
  - Custom Binary: Download: No
  - Current Binary: Samsung Official
  - System Status: Custom
- Tried to software update

  - Message: Your device has been modified, software updates are not available.

What can I do to get rid of the virus and be able to software update normally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you have it unlocked with a custom recovery. If so, use the custom recovery to install a new ROM for your tablet. Find your tablet on http://forum.xda-developers.com/ and you can find either a third-party (i.e. Cyanogenmod, etc.), modified stock, or even completely stock ROM such as this one: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2792979 .

If you don't have a custom recovery, you can find instructions on XDA to use the odin utility to install one.

Wiping the system and data partitions should get rid of the malware but you'll need a new rom to install. If you have an SD card you can put the new rom zip file on the card. If not, you should copy it to the tablet first.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138164/discussion-on-answer-by-mikeatlarge-how-to-fix-badly-virused-android-device-yo).

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution for stopping apps downloading without user intervention:

1. Download TowelRoot and root your device. Then download SuperSU and make it functional.
2. Download CM security, then scan your phone for infected files.
3. Download system app remover (root) and delete all the apps what you found affected in CM security. Uninstall CM SECURITY.
4. Download Titanium Backup and wipe all the data from your phone including cache and apps.
5. Go to recovery mode and reset your device.

This will probably sort out your problem but in case if you find some more apps most of them will stop. Repeat this again and go to system app remover and uninstall your apps one by one, first remove one and wait for some time. If it doesn't stop then remove another and then another. And when it's stopped go to "Recycle Bin" and reinstall all the apps except the last one.

Once your phone will be all right, download a trustworthy antivirus app (say Avast) for future security.

Comment: And yhen you can simply unroot your device by clicking on permanently unroot on supersu.and your devise will me ready for normal update.

Comment: Tey to use sammobile and find the best firmwhere

Comment: Thank You for the idea, but I think the new ROM would be a cleaner solution.

Comment: I would suggest readers to not try this solution as it is inherently risky and probably not at all the best or the easiest or the safest way to go about achieving what the OP has asked for.